# Permissions: Why do I always have to type 'sudo' before every command?

Tags: unix, permissions, user-accounts, sudo

I'm editing theme files in a wordpress site owned by www-data:www-data as my main user 'oma'.  Every time I create a file or edit one, I have to use the sudo command and it gets created as root:root.  Actually, I pretty much have to use it everywhere.  Big pain, as I invariably forget to type this and then my changes aren't saved.

What I'd like is for it to be created as www-data:www-data. I'm even confused as to why I'm being prompted for this, I thought when I added myself to the 'admin' and 'wheel' group in /etc/sudoers.d/oma I would have more privileges.

UNIX permissions just plain boggle my mind.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Adding yourself to wheel gives you the ability to use sudo.
- If you're a user, you typically can't modify another user's files or create new files in a directory owned by them. If you want to do this, change the permissions on the files/directories you want to be open, using chmod:

  `chmod a+rw somename` will give readwrite permissions to all users on the file named somename
- You can sudo to "www-data" rather than to "root" if you want:

  `sudo -u www-data whatever`

  If you have su on your machine you can switch to another user at the shell:

  `su www-data`
- You can change ownership of files using `chown` but don't do this since your web server user probably won't be able to read other users' files.

Comment: BTW, `su` is installed on most systems. You really just need to give root a password in order to use `su` to switch to root. That is done with `sudo passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are good you're having trouble because the folder is already owned by root, so you can't modify the contents. If that's the case, you probably want to change the permissions on the whole tree: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data site-directory`. You may need to mess with your Apache config subsequently, to make sure Apache still has the ability to access and read these files.

All adding things to your sudoers file does is give you more capabilities with the `sudo` command. However, you may be able to placate yourself by adding a `NOPASSWD` flag in /etc/sudoers, like so:

```
%www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You'll still need to use `sudo`, but it won't prompt you for a password. Beware the security implications of doing this, since everyone in the www-data group will thereafter be able to completely hose your machine.

You may want to search out a tutorial on Unix file permissions. They're complex at first, but after you get the hang of them they're quite simple and powerful. [I found this one with a quick googling.](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html)

Comment: Other options (security implication discalimer...) are to use `sudo su` or `sudo -i` to get an interactive root shell.